# Error while installing dr4_driver for ROS1

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, joy-node

I'm trying to install the `ds4_driver` for my ROS Project. I was following the tutorial from http://wiki.ros.org/ds4_driver.

In the end, I can't use `catkin_make` and I'm getting this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:100 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
  'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/coolermann/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/coolermann/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:530: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Same goes with using `catkin_make_isolated`.

I googled and asked ChatGPT and it informed me, that the package is for ROS2.

Since I can't really find an installation for ROS1 and in the wiki it says, that it's for both ROS1 and ROS2, I'm asking here instead. Do you know where/how I can install the `ds4_driver`?

Comment: Did you change the branch to noetic-devel??